# Find a left adjoint to the forgetful functor from the category of monoids to the category of sets

Tags: adjoint-functors

> Find a left adjoint to the forgetful functor from the category of monoids to the category of sets.

I am not sure what to do here. Clearly we must have something akin to free product... I'm sorry I cannot say more, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are on the right track. So, define a functor $F$ from Set to Mon by sending a set $S$ to the free monoid generated by $S$. Now, there will only be one way to define $F$ on arrows, such that the UMP of the adjoint holds.

Answer (score 0):

The *free monoid* on a set $X$ is the collection of finite words with letters
from $X$. We can denote it as $X^*$. Multiplication is concatenation, and
the identity is the empty word.

Each set map $X\to M$, where $M$ is a monoid, extends uniquely to a monoid
map $X^*\to M$, so we have a natural isomorphism
$$\textrm{Map}_{\textrm{Monoid}}(X^*,M)\cong
\textrm{Map}_{\textrm{Set}}(X,M)$$
confirming adjointness.